# Select only one column from mnesia

Tags: select, erlang, mnesia

how can i select only one column from mnesia?
I can select onle column in ets table with this code:

```
ets:match(AllData_TableId, {'_', '$1','_',','_'},3),
```

I need something similar for mnesia.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples found here: **http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Erlang_Programming/Using_mnesia**, look at how the author uses the function `mnesia:match_object/1`, and the consider reading it here more **http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#match_object-1**

However, we are advised to design our mnesia databases and/or tables in a way to avoid the use of this method. This is because it makes mnesia traverse the entire table looking for a match. 
What you need is qlc

```
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").

select(Q)->
    case mnesia:is_transaction() of
        false -> 
            F = fun(QH)-> qlc:e(QH) end,
            %% mnesia:transaction(F);
            mnesia:activity(transaction,F,[Q],mnesia_frag);
        true -> qlc:e(Q)
    end.

-record(book,{title,isbn,price,category}).

book_title({book,ISBN})->
    select(qlc:q([X#book.title || X <- mnesia:table(book),X#book.isbn == ISBN])).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mnesia:select` for that:

```
Spec = [{#tablename{columnname = '$1', _ = '_'}, [], ['$1']}],
{atomic, Result} = mnesia:transaction(fun() -> mnesia:select(tablename, Spec) end),
Result.
```